# Java Eclipse IDE [mySQL Driver cannot be reached]

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have this problem where I tried to connect to mySQL driver by using this code below.I set the code that if I failed to connect to mySQL Driver, a `popup` will appear and say `mySQL Driver cannot be reached` and it does appear. I have imported `mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar` in `Referenced Libraries.

```
package belajarjavaGUI;


    import java.awt.*;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.Statement;


    public class trial extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
                
                Connection con;
                Statement stmt;
                JLabel          lbluser, lblpass;
                JTextField      txtuser;
                JPasswordField  txtpass;
                JButton         btnLogin;
                
                public trial() 
                {
                    settingFrame();
                    settingInterface();
                }
                
                void settingFrame()
                {
                    setLayout(null);
                    setSize(280,200);
                    setTitle("Unit Latihan Industri");
                    setVisible(true);
                    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                     
                }

                void settingInterface()
                {
                    
                    btnLogin = new JButton("Login");
                    btnLogin.setBounds(70, 100, 100, 50);
                    add(btnLogin);
                    btnLogin.addActionListener(this);
                }
                
                public static void main(String[] args) 
                {
                    new trial();

                }

                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
                {
                    if(e.getSource() == btnLogin) {
                
                        //1.load driver
                        try {
                            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                            
                        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
                            
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"mySQL Driver cannot be reached");
                        }
                    }
                }
    }
```

Comment: *Class.forName("com.mysql.jbdc.Driver");* Typo: should be `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");` but you should probably be using  [DriverManager](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-usagenotes-connect-drivermanager.html#connector-j-examples-connection-drivermanager)

Comment: @g00se I tried that. It still doesn't work. It feels like something is blocking the connection but don't know what that is or what kind of setting that is blocking it.

Comment: Please edit your code alteration in your question. Also, place `System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.class.path"));` as the first line of `main` and tell us what it prints

Comment: It says _"mySQL Driver cannot be reached"_, because that is what your code prints when an exception occurs. It is better to print or log the actual exception stacktrace, so you know the actual cause.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");`

Comment: Answers an Stack Overflow must be written in English. This time, I've translated your answer.